# Repeat function if error happens in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call a function in node.js but most likely this function will have an error in it's callback, i want to know the best way to repeat this function number of speciefied time.

Is this way good enought or there is better?

```
var numberOfRetrials = 0;
do{
    send_bus(15, function(err){    // send_bus is synchronus function
        check = err;
    });
    numberOfRetrials++;
} while( (check != null) && (numberOfRetrials <3) );
```

Comment: Is `send_bus` an asynchornous function?

Comment: no it is synchronus function

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var numberOfRetrials = 0;

var task = function () {
    send_bus(15, function(err){
        if(err && numberOfRetrials++ <3){
            task();
        }
    });
};
task();
```

This will work both for sync or async tasks functions. It's a recursive function with an exit condition based in a counter.

Answer (score 1):

Really, since it looks asynchronous to me. I would not put the logic in a loop:

```
var count = 0;
function cb(err) {
    if (!err && count < 3) {
        count++;
        send_bus(15, cb);
    }
}
send_bus(15, cb);
```

Comment: `send_bus`  is synchronus is there a better solution? thanks

Comment: This works for synchronous. For some reason, when I saw your callback I automatically thought in asynchrony but it doesn't have to be this way.